# Why is one array value not being used? Processing 3 (java)

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I am working on creating a random dungeon generator for a game I am going to make. I just barely did the basics. In order to avoid having to make 20 different variables for the 20 different rectangles I drew, I used two arrays called rx and ry. However, when I went to draw the rectangles using:

```
rect(rx[19], rx[19], 50, 50)
```

It didnt put the last rectangle in the correct spot. Rather than putting it at the value that is determined by my code, it always puts rectangle 19 at 0, 0. I am not entirely sure that it is in fact rectangle 19, but I'm assuming it is. I made my two arrays using:

```
int[] rx = new int[20];
```

and

```
int[] ry = new int[20];
```

Anything helps. Here is the rest of my code just in case it will be useful, however, if you would like me to only give the important bits, tell me. Thanks!

```
int gx = 400;
int gy = 400;
int gDir;
int gCheckX;
int gCheckY;
int[] rx = new int[20];
int[] ry = new int[20];
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  size(700, 700);
}

void draw() {
  fill(0);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(#696969);
  if(i < 19) {
    i++;
    gDir = int(random(1, 5));
    if(gDir == 1) {
      gCheckX = 25;
      gCheckY = -25;
    }
    if(gDir == 2) {
      gCheckX = 25;
      gCheckY = 75;
    }
    if(gDir == 3) {
      gCheckX = -25;
      gCheckY = 25;
    }
    if(gDir == 4) {
      gCheckX = 75;
      gCheckY = 25;
    }
    while(get(gCheckX, gCheckY) == color(105, 105, 105)) {
      gDir = int(random(1, 5));
      if(gDir == 1) {
        gCheckX = 25;
        gCheckY = -25;
      }
      if(gDir == 2) {
        gCheckX = 25;
        gCheckY = 75;
      }
      if(gDir == 3) {
        gCheckX = -25;
        gCheckY = 25;
      }
      if(gDir == 4) {
        gCheckX = 75;
        gCheckY = 25;
      }
    }
    if(gDir == 1) {gy -= 50;}
    if(gDir == 2) {gy += 50;}
    if(gDir == 3) {gx -= 50;}
    if(gDir == 4) {gx += 50;}
    rx[i] = gx;
    ry[i] = gy;
    println(rx[i] + " " + ry[i]);
  }
  else {
    rect(rx[0], ry[0], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[1], ry[1], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[2], ry[2], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[3], ry[3], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[4], ry[4], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[5], ry[5], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[6], ry[6], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[7], ry[7], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[8], ry[8], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[9], ry[9], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[10], ry[10], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[11], ry[11], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[12], ry[12], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[13], ry[13], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[14], ry[14], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[15], ry[15], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[16], ry[16], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[17], ry[17], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[18], ry[18], 50, 50);
    rect(rx[19], ry[19], 50, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: rx[19] does not appear to get set because of your if (i < 19)

Comment: So when I make it 20 it gives me an error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Oh, I see, because of the i++. You're right. What if you start int i = -1? (because otherwise where does rx[0] get set)

Comment: Oh that worked! Don't know how it works but amazing thank you!

Comment: Why does this have a java tag? The language. Is c-like, but not java.

Comment: It has a java tag because processing has multiple modes. The one I had selected was titled "java". However there is also other modes such as python

Answer (score 0):

Got it answered by @Jeremy Kahan. I just had to set `i` to `-1` and it fixed itself!

Comment: It works because since the first thing you do inside your if block is i++, you were working with 1, 2, 3, ..., 18, and 19, but never with index 0. Starting at -1 fixed that so you worked with all twenty entries (whose indices are 0 to 19)

Comment: Or you could put the i++ at the end of the loop, or use a real for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was my answer, I'm writing it as an answer. The key was to initialize `int i = -1;` rather than `int i = 0;`

It works because since the first thing you do inside your if block is i++, you were working with 1, 2, 3, ..., 18, and 19, but never with index 0. Starting at -1 fixed that so you worked with all twenty entries (whose indices are 0 to 19).